# Scrapy spider scrape only 2 pages and don't go to the next page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

when I run this code, the spider only crawls 2 pages and stop. It doesn't go to the next page.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class P1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'p1'
    allowed_domains = ['www.visit.ferienmesse.ch']
    start_urls = ['https://www.visit.ferienmesse.ch/de/aussteller']

    def parse(self, response):

        for data in response.xpath('//ul[@class="ngn-search-list ngn-mobile-filter"]/li'):
            yield {
                'Link': response.urljoin(data.xpath('.//h2[@class="ngn-content-box-title"]/a/@href').get()),
                'Title': data.xpath('//h2[@class="ngn-content-box-title"]/a/bdi/text()').get(),
                'Address': data.xpath('.//span[@class="ngn-hallname"]/text()').get(),
                'Code': data.xpath('.//span[@class="ngn-stand"]/text()').get()
            }

        next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="arrow "]/a/@href').get()

        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: It works `response.css('.arrow > a[rel="next"]::attr(href)').get()` or `response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"arrow")]/a[@rel="next"]/@href').get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the next page selector to this and see if it works:

```
next_page = response.css('.pagination li.arrow a[rel="next"]::attr(href)').get()
```

**Reason**

From the second page on, you have 2 li with the class of `arrow`.

- One for the previous page
- One for the next page

You can read more about selectors here:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: it worked, thanks. Can you tell me why the XPath expression didn't work even though it was correct?

Comment: Glad I could help. Please check the answer as the correct answer.
I will update my answer with your comment question. ;)